# Animate transitions in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, fadein, transition

I have a UIScrollView that holds UIImageViews.

I'd like to animate the transition between views using a fading style. So, if we are at index 0, and we move on, the image at index 1 will display OVER the image 0.

Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: If you want to transition between the views using a fading effect, what is the purpose of hosting them in a UIScrollView?

Comment: @Krumelur Because the default behaviour is classic UIScrollView, but there is a "slideshow" mode that uses this fading effect.

Comment: Its a tricky problem since you are moving the content offset of your scrollview to show the new view, so its difficult to fade the transition at the same time. What you could do is to draw a copy of your current view on top of the view you will be scrolling to, adjust the content offset to set the scrollview to its new location and then fade out your copy exposing the view behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really simple way of fading between two views:

```
saveFrame = self.imageView2.frame;
self.imageView2.frame = self.imageView1.frame;
self.imageView2.alpha = 0;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0]; 
self.imageView1.alpha = 0;
self.imageView2.alpha = 1; 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: But the imageView1 and imageView2 have different frame.origin.x, they are in a UIScrollView, so changing only the alpha doesn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Couldn't you just move the view before [UIView beginAnimations ...]? Or as part of the animation.

Comment: I've solved with this idea. I had to move the imageView1 to the frame of imageView2 and later restore it.